# Setting Default Value in Select Menus With react-hook-form

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form, chakra-ui

I'm trying to set the default value of a select menu from [chakra-react-select](https://npmjs.com/package/chakra-react-select) in a form but i am unsuccessful in acheiving this.

This is the code:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                    <Flex justifyContent="space-between" mt={8}>
                        <Flex flexDir={"column"} justifyContent={"space-between"} align={"flex-start"}>
                            <Heading size={"sm"}>Prefix</Heading>
                            <Text color={"gray.300"}>Configure the prefix for the guild.</Text>
                            <Input
                                paddingTop={"1px"}
                                placeholder="Enter prefix here"
                                size='md'
                                {...register("prefix", { maxLength: { value: 5, message: "Max length exceeded" }, minLength: { value: 1, message: "Minimum length is 1" }, required: { value: true, message: "This field is required." } })}
                            />
                        </Flex>
                        <Flex flexDir={"column"} justifyContent={"space-between"} align={"flex-end"}>
                            <Heading size={"sm"}>Language</Heading>
                            <Text color={"gray.300"}>Configure the language for the guild.</Text>
                            <Controller
                                name="language"
                                control={control}
                                defaultValue=" English"
                                rules={selectMenuRules.language}
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                    <Select className='select-menu' options={availableLanguages} {...field} />
                                )}
                            />
                        </Flex>
                    </Flex>
                    <br />
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a string  *English* as `defaultValue` seems to be the issue. You can try using something like `availableLanguages[0].value` for `defaultValue` prop.

Edit:

You can try using just `availableLanguages[0]`. Also React Hook Form advanced usage section have some examples for react-select with Controller component. These might help.

https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage

Comment: That does not work for me

Comment: Please check this git repo for the whole code: https://github.com/gaurishhs/Groot-Dashboard

File which has error: https://github.com/gaurishhs/Groot-Dashboard/blob/main/pages/manage/%5Bid%5D/settings.tsx

Comment: Ok. How about just availableLanguages[0]